# Update the first_name and last_name column and switch them

Tags: oracle11g

I need to update the first_name column with the last_name and vise versa; first_name and last_name columns got switched during load. Basically, I need to figure out how to switch them back in correct order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a simple `update`.  This will flip the data in the two columns

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET first_name = last_name,
       last_name  = first_name
```

Comment: Then both column will have same value. Isn't it?

Comment: @Rahul - No.  `first_name` will have the value that was previously in `last_name` and `last_name` will have the value that was in `first_name`.  SQL is set-based not procedural.

Comment: Thanks Justin, i am confused with your update statement. I have about 3000 rows that needs to switched, how this update will work

Comment: @user4826005 - The update I posted will run for every row in the table.  It will take the current value from the `last_name` column and move it to the `first_name` column.  It will take the current value from the `first_name` column and move it to the `last_name` column.  After it is run, the `first_name` and `last_name` values for every row will be swapped.  That appears to be what you asked for in your question.  If that is not what you are looking for, show us what you have, what you want, and what the `update` statement I posted doesn't do that you want it to do.